# Rcpp upgrading legacy code questions

Tags: r, mingw, codeblocks, rcpp

I am taking over a project which involves upgrading to the latest version of Rcpp and thus I have to upgrade all the old style API calls (which is compatible with the CLassic version I believe). As there is no full API documentation, I am having to do this by trial and error and noting any "undefined reference" errors on linking and then looking through the vignettes/examples. The compile works fine but the errors arise on linking against \inst\libs\RLink.dll. I have manged to convert a lot of the code (mainly using Rcpp::List to extract and pack incoming and outgoing function parameters) but I simply cannot get equivalents for the following:

1. Rprintf or Rf_error and forward_exception_to_r.
2. R_NilValue
3. Rf_install

I am using Code::Blocks 10.05 IDE with RTools installed and Mingw64 referenced explicitly in the toolchain with the GNU GCC Compiler selected. I'd be grateful for any heads up. Thanks.

edit:

I do have #include  and before that  and  (there was a series of errors that were occuring because I had included iostream before Rcpp, which was strange.

Answer (score 1):

Can you please provide some concrete examples, maybe even on the rcpp-devel list?  The porting approach works, I too have ported legacy code from the 'classic' Rcpp API, and so have others on the list.

But you do *not* have to port. The short vignette in the [RcppClassic](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RcppClassic) package has details on how to use it in case you want to maintain the old API.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for your response. The problem is that RcppClassic is not 64 bit compatible which is the main reason I am porting. I will bring this up on the devel-list.

Comment: If there is an issue with 64bit, please do bring it and we try to fix it. For what it is worth, I run a a 64bit OS too and it works fine there with any g++ version between 4.3 and 4.5. If Windows needs special hand-holding I am sure we can work that out too.

Comment: Also, RcppClassic built fine at CRAN in 32 and 64 bit Windows so make sure your tools are correctly setup: http://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_RcppClassic.html